# What network settings are best for Counter-Strike: Source after the update?

Tags: counter-strike-source, source-engine

After the update my kpd has plummetted and I was wondering if some of the settings could do with tweaking.  I am getting a lag spike most rounds and reg does appear worse than usual.

I have:

- `cl_interp` = 0.045
- `cl_cmdrate` = 66
- `cl_updaterate` = 66

I have turned off HDR and turned every graphic setting down.

Are there better settings that I could use, for general play on a very active server (20-50 players)?

Answer (score 4):

Seeing as no-one has answered this question so far, I'll try.

First of all, I wouldn't suggest meddling with cvars to alleviate lag. Valve has worked pretty hard on their networking code, and changing their defaults will usually only make the problem worse.

Do you have ping lag or graphics lag? If it's the former first eliminate all the primary suspects, someone using the connection, or just try a server closer to you.

If it's graphics lag you might want to try getting a better computer if you have such lag with every setting on low.

Comment: No-one else is using my connection, which is a 20mB Virgin cable connection that I'm cabled to (not wireless) - although contention could be an issue it really shouldn't be at 1am.  The keyboard is wired as is the mouse.  The computer is a year old and was mid-priced when bought - it could be a poor graphics card I guess but I'm getting 50 fps.  The problem could be the server I'm on - but it is UK based.

Answer (score 3):

After the latest update, `cmd` and `update` are locked, so you can leave them alone. However, you should change the following settings to these values:

`cl_interp 0.0`
`cl_interp_ratio 1`

Also, when you you use `net_graph 1` and you see your lerp flickering in color, it means the server is rather crappy. It should stay one solid color. If it's flickering, don't blame your config, blame the server. :D

If you still need any help, you can add me on Steam: harrie_aardappel

Another tip: Never think hit registration will be good on a server with more than 20 players on it. The more players there are on a server, the crappier it will get.